# Window 8's start screen does not create new process?

Tags: windows-8

For example, I have started a visual studio instance, then I want to start a new visual studio instance in the windows 8's start screen with clicking the visual studio icon. But rather than starting a new instance, the system just bring me to the existing visual studio instance.

How could I set the default action for clicking to start a new process rather than switch to the existing process?

Thanks.

Comment: I knew there was one here someplace -- nice catch! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the icon on your start screen, and select "open new window" in the options popup.

Here's an example:

[image: opening a new instance of a program]

Shift-Click will also open a new instance.  (Thanks for that tip.)

Comment: Although this is correct (and probably the closest the OP is going to get) it doesn't really answer "how to set 'open a new instance' as default".

Comment: @techie007: I found a duplicate and deleted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual (i.e. Windows 7) way works just fine: Middle-click. Alternatively, Shift-Click works too.